# Security considerations when creating a mobile app using PhoneGap

Tags: security, cordova

I'm a beginner in creating mobile apps with phonegap. I have some doubts on security aspects, when creating a mobile app with phonegap.

1. I want to create an app that accesses a Web service, e.g. a REST service created using Jersey. Now, am I correct in thinking that a hacker can easily see the security keys/authentication mechanism used, to authenticate the client (on a mobile app) with the server (where REST API is to be used)?
2. In general, can a hacker easily access all data being sent by the mobile app (which was created using phonegap)?
3. Can a hacker disassemble a phonegap app to obtain original code? Wont he get the native code (e.g. Objective C in case of ios)? Or can he decompile even that into original phonegap code (ie html+js)? How do I prevent my code from being decompiled? Is this scenario the same as for most other languages i.e. hackers with powerful PCs can hack into just about any program/software? Is there some way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Allright, first take a deep breath. You are probably not going to like some of my answers but you'll be living with the same issues that we all are.

1. The best thing to do in this case is to use something like the [KeyChain](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Keychain) plugin to retrieve your security keys from the native side.
2. You can take PhoneGap out of the question because it applies to any situation where  you send unencrypted data between a client and server. Anyone can easily listen in using a number of tools including Wireshark or Ethereal. If you need to communicate with a sever it should be done on an encrypted, HTTPS or SSL, connection.
3. First I think you are under the mistaken impression that PhoneGap compiles your HTML/JS code into Obj-C. It does not. If the user uncompresses your app they will be able to read your HTML/JS. Also, they'll be able to decompile your Obj-C code as well. This does not take a powerful PC or even an experienced hacker. Pretty much anyone can do it.

My advice to you is not to worry about it. Put your time into creating a truly great app. The people who will pay for it will pay for it. The folks who decompile it would never buy the app no matter what. The more time you take trying to combat the hackers takes away from the time you could use to make your app greater. Also, most anti-hacking measures just make life harder for your actual users so in fact they are counter productive.

Comment: i have a few questions for you- nowadays a lot of public REST APIs use OAuth, or Amazon's model (for AWS)- wont these be sufficient for mobile apps? (With ref to your answer, I think both OAuth and Amazon's model do use HTTPS...) Also, HTTPS wont be possible with local apps since some functionality of Phonegap requires local web page only?... Thanks

Comment: OAuth works good with PhoneGap apps. Well if all the pages are local then there is no communication with the outside work and thereby nothing for hackers to sniff.

Comment: Mr. MacDonald's reply, while well-intentioned, does not account for the developers who are concerned about app uncompression for this reason instead: Other developers may read the code, pirate it, and use it to develop a competing app. That's a serious and legitimate concern, and needs to be taken into consideration when pondering the use of PhoneGap.

Comment: Oh, you did not just "Mr. MacDonald" me? Just kidding. Sure that is a legitimate concern but it is not limited to only PhoneGap or hybrid apps. I can take a native Android or iOS app and decompile it and read your code just as easily as I can with hybrid apps. So I don't think that is a good reason to exclude PhoneGap when you are determining what technologies to use when building mobile apps.

Comment: There are plenty tools available to obfuscate the code. It runs on the apk file, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR -**
Consider that you are coding a website and all code ( html and js ) will be visible to user with
[Crtl+Shift+i as in browsers](https://www.howtogeek.com/416108/how-to-view-the-html-source-in-google-chrome/#:%7E:text=Inspect%20Source%20Using%20Developer%20Tools&text=Open%20Chrome%20and%20head%20to,the%20webpage%20you%27re%20viewing.)
Some points for ensuring maximum security

1. If your using backend then recheck everything coming from the app
2. [All attacks possible on websites (XSS, redicting to malacious webistes , cloning webistes, etc are possible )](https://research.securitum.com/security-problems-of-apache-cordova-steal-the-entire-contents-of-the-phone_s-memory-card-with-one-xss/)
3. All the data sent to the app will finally be available in some js variables / resource files , Since all variables are accessible by hacker so is all the data sent to app EVEN IF YOU ARE USING THE MOST SECURE DATA TRANSMISSION  MECHANISMS
4. As Simon correctly said in his ans , phonegap or cordova does not *convert* html / js to native code . Html / Js is available *as-it-is* 
   Cordova also explicitly mentions this in their official statement

> **Do not assume that your source code is secure** 
> Since a Cordova application is built from HTML and JavaScript assets that get packaged in a native container, you should not consider your code to be secure. It is possible to reverse engineer a Cordova application.

5.Mainly all the techniques which are used by websites to prevent their code from being cloned / easily understood are applicable even here (Mainly it includes converting js code into hard to read format - obfuscating code)

6.Comparing native apps with cordova/phonegap apps native apps , I would say that cordova are easier for hacker only because of lack of awareness between cordova developers who do not take enough measures to secure it  and lack of readily available(one click ) mechanisms to directly obfuscate the code vs in android proguard

**Sample Cordova App Hacking (NOTE:Phonegap also works in similar way)**

I'll show an example to show how easy is it for hacker to hack a cordova app(where developer has taken no efforts in obfuscating the code )
basically we start with unzipping the apk files (apks can be unzipped like zip files )
The contents inside will be similar to this
[image]
The source code for cordova apps is present in /assets/www/ folder
[image]
As you can see all the contents including any databases that you have packed with the app are visible(see last 2 rows have a db file )
Along with it any other resources are also directly visible (text files/js / html/ audio / video / etc)
All the views / controllers are visible and editable too
Further exploring the contents we find a PaymentController.js file
[image]

***Opening it we can directly see the js code and other comments*** 
[image]
here we note that after user performs payment if it is successful then successCallback is called else cancelCallback is called.

Hacker can simply replace the two functions so that when payment is not successful successCallback is called .
In absence of other checks the hacker has successfully bypassed payment.